# Google Search Console API : HttpError 403 “Search Analytics load quota exceeded. Learn about usage limits:”

Tags: python, api, google-apis-explorer

I have a python script that extracts data from Google search console API.  The code worked for over 2 months and suddenly started getting this error "HttpError 403" Search Analytics load quota exceeded.
Learn about usage limits:".
I also checked our quotas and we're nowhere near being close to the max. For today, I show 20 requests against a 100,000,000 query max.

Has anyone else had this happen? Any ideas on where I can look for solutions?

Comment: Welcome to so, as you are not showing your script, it is hard to tell maybe due to multiple  request tries.

Comment: there are 7 different reasons provided for 403 Rate limit exceeded error, see here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_403_error_usage_limit_exceeded